# React controlled component does not autocomplete in Firefox

Tags: firefox, reactjs

When using a controlled input in React the autocomplete feature does not work in Firefox, but it does in Chrome. So it has nothing to do with the attribute autocomplete off on the form element since I didn't use that.

This is the code I use to render the controlled input element:

```
<input style={inputStyle} id={this.props.id} type={this.props.type} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
```

And this is the onChange function that is passed into this component from the parent component (for the email field):

```
_updateEmail(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value.substr(0, 100)});
}
```

And here are 2 screenshots to show it doesn't work in Firefox but does in Chrome.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

If I turn the controlled input into a normal one, it does work with Firefox. So that's the really weird part.

Comment: the value prop for <input needs to have an `=` between the prop name and value

Comment: ah yeah sorry that's a copy paste error cause of formatting, its correct in the code, i'll edit it quickly

Comment: I hope you found a solution. Could you please share it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159) in React. Your best bet to solve is issue is to disable autocomplete, or use the [auto-fill](https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event) polyfil.

Alternatively, you can handle this case outside of ReactJS and using DOM directly, as outlined in the issue:

```js
export default class Input extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onFieldChange: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    value: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._listener = setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.input || this._previousValue === this.input.value) {
        return;
      }

      this._previousValue = this.input.value;

      const evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      evt.initEvent('input', true, true);
      this.input.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }, 20);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._listener);
  }

  refInput = (input) => this.input = input;

  render() {
    const { label,
      value,
      onFieldChange,
    } = this.props;

    this.input = this.input || { value };

    return (
        <input
            value={this.input.value}
            onChange={onFieldChange}
            ref={this.refInput}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No that is not the problem, I don't think you understand the issue that I have. When the autocomplete works it does fire the onChange event. The problem is that in firefox the autocomplete just doesn't work for controlled components.